# preserve environmental variables with find -exec

Tags: find, environment-variables

Is it possible to preserve environmental variables with find -exec?  I don't see any options using the FreeBSD version of find.  I can switch to a for loop if absolutely required, but was hoping to use the brevity of exec as well as it is faster.

The other option I can think of isn't pretty and that is dumping the environment and then reading it back in in the command I'm executing.

EDIT:

```
find . -type f -name '*/*.patch/go' -exec go install {} \;
```

In this example, I want go to use the http proxy.  I already have code that tells git to configure a global http proxy (above this).

So, from the example below, I need to preface this with sh?  Why?

Comment: I'm curious about the command that made you think the environment variables are not inherited. Or is it about a child process trying to alter the variables of the (grand)parent shell?

Comment: *"So, from the example below, I need to preface this with sh?"* - for a counter example try `FOO=bar find . -type f -exec awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["FOO"]}' \;`

Comment: @they, you're right - I need to debug my scripts some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child processes always inherit the environment.  This means that the utility that you launch from `find ... -exec` will have access to the environment.

Testing this:

```bsh
$ unset -v myvar1 myvar2
$ export myvar1='hello world'
$ myvar2='not exported'
$ find . -exec sh -c 'for pathname do printf "found %s, myvar1=%s, myvar2=%s\n" "$pathname" "$myvar1" "$myvar2"; done' sh {} +
found ., myvar1=hello world, myvar2=
found ./.bash_profile, myvar1=hello world, myvar2=
found ./.bashrc, myvar1=hello world, myvar2=
found ./.yashrc, myvar1=hello world, myvar2=
found ./.zshrc, myvar1=hello world, myvar2=
```

Here I clear the two shell variables `myvar1` and `myvar2`, then I set them and export `myvar1` but not `myvar2`.  This means `myvar1` would be inherited by any child process while `myvar2` would not be inherited.

As you can see in the output from `find`, the exported `myvar1` is available inside the single-quoted `sh -c` script that `find` calls through `-exec` for batches of found pathnames.

You may also use an assignment in front of the `find` command to set the value of an environment variable without setting it in the current shell.  This is standard syntax and not just how `find` works.

```bsh
$ unset -v myvar1 myvar2
$ myvar2='now in environment' find . -exec sh -c 'for pathname do printf "found %s, myvar1=%s, myvar2=%s\n" "$pathname" "$myvar1" "$myvar2"; done' sh {} +
found ., myvar1=, myvar2=now in environment
found ./.bash_profile, myvar1=, myvar2=now in environment
found ./.bashrc, myvar1=, myvar2=now in environment
found ./.yashrc, myvar1=, myvar2=now in environment
found ./.zshrc, myvar1=, myvar2=now in environment
```

Another example of this syntax without using `find`:

```bsh
$ unset -v x
$ x='hello there' sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$x"'
hello there
$ printf "%s\n" "$x"
```

Note how `x` is not set in the current shell (the last `printf` outputs an empty line).